# How I can add minor breaks year wise? Also I want to show X-axis labels for every year

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]I have posted a snapshot of the data frame and the plot I already generated.

```
Quaterly_cumulative_returns %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, y = Return,
             colour = BANK, 
             group = BANK)) + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=10))+ #change legend text font size
  geom_line(aes(linetype= BANK),size=0.75)+
  labs(x="Quaterly 01APR2004-31MAR2022",   
    y="Cumulative Return ")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="gray", size=0.5)) + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 15)+
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of data. We cannot use these to recreate your plot. Instead, add the output of `dput(Quaterly_cumulative_returns)` into a code block in your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I take it from the styling of your plot that you want yearly *axis ticks* rather than grid lines. Axis ticks occur at major breaks rather than minor breaks, so you need to create all the major breaks but only label every 5th year:

```r
p1 <- Quaterly_cumulative_returns %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, y = Return,
             colour = BANK, 
             group = BANK)) + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=10))+ 
  geom_line(aes(linetype= BANK),size=0.75)+
  labs(x="Quaterly 01APR2004-31MAR2022",   
       y="Cumulative Return ")+
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2004-01-01"), as.Date("2023-01-01"),
                            by = "year"),
               labels = ~ ifelse(as.numeric(format(.x, "%Y")) %% 5 == 0,
                                 format(.x, "%Y"), "")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="gray", size=0.5)) + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 15)

p1
```

[image]

As for tables of values every year under the x axis, this is going to look messy because you don't really have enough horizontal space to do it, but you could achieve it by building a table-like plot and adding it below your main plot with the patchwork package:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

p2 <- Quaterly_cumulative_returns %>% 
  filter(as.numeric(format(Year, "%m")) == 3) %>%
  mutate(Return = round(Return)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Year, BANK)) +
  geom_tile(fill = "white", color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Return)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_line(color = "white"),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_blank())

(p1 / p2) + plot_layout(heights = c(3, 1))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

There was no useable data provided in the question, so here is a reproducible data set I used for demonstration purposes with the same names and basic structure as the data in the question (including the misspelled data frame name)

```r
set.seed(2)

Quaterly_cumulative_returns <- 
data.frame(BANK = rep(c("Axis Bank", "IndusInd Bank", "NIFTY Bank Index", 
             "NIFTY Index", "RBL Bank", "Yes Bank"), each = 75),
           Year = rep(seq(as.Date("2004-03-30"), by = "3 month",
                          length = 75), 6),
           Return = c(replicate(6, 100 + cumsum(rnorm(75, 50, 100)))))
```

Comment: This is very useful....thank you so much.....ALso I've added the desired graph which I made in excel....is it possible to generate that chart ?

Comment: @Jimi13ABC What specifically is it about the Excel chart that you want to see in the ggplot chart? They look very similar to me. Is it the grid lines, the labelling style, the line types? All of these are possible to implement in ggplot, but there are many good sources out there to explain how these things are done. Is there a specific question you would like answered?

Comment: Yes, the grid lines and the x-axis values (2004,2005.....2022).